# Insert multiple rows without using CURSOR SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly complex query which insert multiple rows into a table from multiple tables. Its works fine but I really don't want to use cursor as some blog says cursor took long time for execution (of course it depends). I hope I could find alternative way for minimize my execution time or cursor complexity. Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @employeeid int;
DECLARE @joiningdate date;
DECLARE @quitdate date;
DECLARE @eodrefs int,@amounts decimal;

select @employeeid=HRMS_Employee.ID,@joiningdate=HRMS_Employee.Joining_Date,@quitdate=HRMS_Employee.QuitDate 
from HRMS_Employee where HRMS_Employee.Present_Status=1 and ID=4

DECLARE @tabEodRecord table(eodref  int,amount decimal)
insert INTO @tabEodRecord (eodref,amount)

select HRMS_EodRecord.Eod_RefFk,HRMS_EodRecord.ActualAmount from HRMS_EodRecord join HRMS_Employee on HRMS_EodRecord.EmployeeId=HRMS_Employee.ID 
where HRMS_EodRecord.Status=1 and HRMS_EodRecord.EmployeeId=@employeeid

IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','PayrollInfoCursor')>=-1
    BEGIN
     DEALLOCATE PayrollInfoCursor
    END

DECLARE PayrollInfoCursor CURSOR
FOR (select eodref,amount from @tabEodRecord) 
OPEN PayrollInfoCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM PayrollInfoCursor INTO  @eodrefs,@amounts
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
insert HRMS_PayrollInfo (PayrollFK,EmployeeIdFk,Eod_ReferenceFk,Amount,PaymentDate,[Status],AlertActive,Entry_By,Entry_Date,Update_By,Update_Date)
select 26,@employeeid,@eodrefs,@amounts,getdate(),1,1,1,getdate(),1,getdate()
FETCH NEXT FROM PayrollInfoCursor INTO  @eodrefs,@amounts
END
CLOSE PayrollInfoCursor  
DEALLOCATE PayrollInfoCursor
```

I hope there is something like this (however this won't work) because **subquery returns multiple rows**

```
insert HRMS_PayrollInfo (PayrollFK,EmployeeIdFk,Eod_ReferenceFk,Amount,PaymentDate,[Status],AlertActive,Entry_By,Entry_Date,Update_By,Update_Date)
select 26,@employeeid,(select eodref from tabEodRecord),(select amountfrom tabEodRecord),getdate(),1,1,1,getdate(),1,getdate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell based on the code you've presented, you can reduce it down to the following...

```
DECLARE @employeeid INT;

INSERT dbo.HRMS_PayrollInfo (PayrollFK, EmployeeIdFk, Eod_ReferenceFk, Amount, PaymentDate, Status, AlertActive, Entry_By, Entry_Date, Update_By, Update_Date)
SELECT
    26,
    @employeeid,
    er.Eod_RefFk,
    er.ActualAmount,
    GETDATE(),
    1,
    1,
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    1,
    GETDATE()   
FROM
    dbo.HRMS_EodRecord er
    --JOIN dbo.HRMS_Employee e
    --  ON er.EmployeeId = e.ID
WHERE
    er.Status = 1
    AND er.EmployeeId = @employeeid;
```

Comment: thanks. That's amazing. I didn't see actually how simple it is. thanks once again.

Comment: @Parvez - Not a problem. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes to see the problem from a different perspective.